# How to selectively process parts of a large dataset without reloading the page in Django?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have an app which allows the user to upload a large datafile, process its contents into a python object (not Django model), and then present a summary of the contents to the user. In other words, the big data is present in the view and summarised to the template.
 The user then selects which of the content sections to save to the database, and submits the form to do so.

I'm wrestling with how to pass the python object to the AJAX-called function without having to do all the processing again?

I've used AJAX in the past and have read the answers to suggestions for not reloading pages etc, but none of them have involved passing large objects from within a view.

```
    # retrieve the file
    storage = TemporaryParseStorage.objects.get(id=item_id)

    # open the file from memory
    f = open(storage.file.path, "r")
    file_text = f.read()

    # Parse the file:
    parser = Parser()

    # Process its contents to create the object - I want to store this
    # object and call its member functions based on a button click in the template
    objectIWantToKeep = parser.parseModel(file_text)  

    # Builds tree for preview
    tree = build_tree_from_model(storage, model)  

    context = {
        'storage': storage,
        'model_name': model.name(),
        'tree': tree
    }

    return render(request, 'main/upload_check.html', context)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a cache like Redis etc. or database to keep your processed objects temporarily?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) I'd thought about saving to the database temporarily using a serialiser or pickler, but am not clear how the functions attached to my object would work?  Am currently busy googling caching ...